# How to increase the size of the Screenshot Thumbnails in ExtentReports 4.0.9

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I'm trying to customize ExtentReports 4.0.9
When I'm opening report after test fails, It displays screenshot as very small thumbnails. How can i increase size of the Thumbnail.

I've tried extent-config.xml

```
<!-- custom styles -->
    <styles>
      <![CDATA[
        .featherlight-image {   border: 1px solid #f6f7fa;   cursor: zoom-in;    width: 100px; }
      ]]>
    </styles>
```

Screenshot is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ37j.jpg

but it didn't work.
Please suggest How can i Increase the size of thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched about it and finally got the solution for my problem.
I have added some **CSS** code from htmlreported of Extent Report 4.

```
htmlReporter.config().setCSS(".r-img { width: 30%; }");
report=new ExtentReports();
report.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

I have added above code when configuring ExtentReport.

I hope it will work for someone who face the same situation.