# Change style of ExtendReports with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

Do we have feasibility to change styling of Extend Report in selenium. As example, pass is highlighted in green , is there any way to change the colour of pass test cases to some other colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the changes in the **extent-config.xml** and load it at the time of running the scripts under **@BeforeSuite**

By using this external XML file (extent-config.xml), we could change the details such as Report Theme (either standard or dark), Report Title, Document Title etc., We use extent object and use loadConfig() method to load this XML file.

```
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite() {
extentReport = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty(“user.dir”) + “/test-output/ExtentReport.html”,true);
extentReport.addSystemInfo(“Host Name”, “XYZ”).addSystemInfo(“Environment”, “Dev”).addSystemInfo(“User Name”, “ABC”);
extentReport.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty(“user.dir”) + “\\extent-config.xml”));
}
```

Reference [LINK](https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/blob/master/extent-config.xml)  [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370624/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-screenshot-thumbnails-in-extentreports-4-0-9)